# Installing Windows on a Mac Pro 5.1 on top of open core

Tags: windows, mac-pro

I'm running a Mac Pro 5.1 (original 2010) with Big Sur on open core with the following specs:

- CPU: 2 x 2,9 GHz 6-Core Intel Xeon
- Memory: 48 GB 1333 MHz DDR3
- GPU: Radeon RX 580 8 GB
- SSD 1: 500GB SSD running Big Sur/opencore
- SSD 2: 256GB SSD currently containing Catalina, will be the Windows disk
- HDD 1: 80GB HD used for data only.

I want to install Windows next to Big Sur on my 256GB SSD SSD2) and every now and then boot into it, preferably via open core.

I found some various guides/posts that concerned me a bit on the approach. One stated that you should not use a USB drive for installation as it might temper with the firmware an potentially corrupt it.

https://crystalidea.com/blog/classic-mac-pro-and-windows

I've also found tutorials that explicitly say to do use an usb drive.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hRuLPQCzOXQ

Other suggest using Rufus (http://rufus.ie) to install Windows.

I have a few questions:

- Does anyone have experience with installing Windows on a Mac Pro 5.1
- Is any of these procedures up to date?
- If I corrupt the firmware, will I be able to recover it?
- Can I use the RX 580 while installing or do I need to fit in a boot screen gpu for the installation?
- Does anyone have more recommendations/advice suggestions for this?

Comment: Try to ask one specific question in the future.
Having said that, I've followed the instructions below without any problem on my Mac Pro 5,1. https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/opencore-on-the-mac-pro.2207814/

Comment: The firmware problem isn’t using USB it is booting Windows in UEFI mode with incorrect Open Core settings. It can brick your Mac by writing too much to private NVRAM which can’t be cleared. Back your BIOS up first and read carefully the link above from @Volsk.

Comment: Thx, how would I back up the bios? I assumed the Mac didn't have one?

Comment: You can backup firmware using ROMTool from here http://dosdude1.com/apps/ (password for the zip is  “rom”). Whether you want to call that BIOS is a matter of opinion, perhaps I used the wrong term.  What stars the computer is what I meant.  In any case it is what you might need to rewrite to the chip. Best ask on macrumors though unless you have a specific question.

Comment: Thx for the help so far, I got a question about the link. It states that the sample configuration contains the required setting to protect it for refi windows. What settings is this? I need this because I already have a opencore configuration.

Comment: Do you want to use the optical drive to install Windows? The current 64 bit version of Windows 10 would require burning a DL DVD. The would allow you to install a BIOS booting Windows 10. If you do not want to use the optical drive, then the Windows installer can be booted from an internal drive. However, this work require a boot loader such as Grub. I am not sure how open core would complicate this.

Comment: Setting `ProtectSecureBoot` to ‘true’ *should* prevent Windows writing certificates - https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/opencore-on-the-mac-pro.2207814/page-58